# Using recursive CTE in SQL I have to find all the Countries that are 3 borders away from Germany

Tags: sql, rdbms

| Country 1 | Country 2 | Border Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | France | 10000 |
| Spain | France | 10000 |
| Portugal | Spain | 10000 |
| Austria | Germany | 10000 |

From the above table we can see that France and Austria are 1 Border away from Germany. Spain is 2 borders away from Germany (because German and Spain have France as their neighbor, hence we have to cross 2 borders to reach Spain). And Portugal is 3 borders away from Germany (here we have to cross France and Spain to reach Portugal).

Using recursive CTE in SQL how can I find all the countries which are 3 borders away from Germany ?

Note: A single country can be in any Column (Either Country1 column or in Country2 column).

```
WITH RECURSIVE THREE_BORDERS_AWAY AS (
    SELECT Country1, Country2, 1 AS BORDERS_AWAY
    FROM borders
    WHERE Country1 = "D" OR Country2 = "D"
    
    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT Country1, Country2, TBA.BORDERS_AWAY + 1
    FROM THREE_BORDERS_AWAY AS TBA
    WHERE BORDERS_AWAY < 3
)
SELECT * FROM THREE_BORDERS_AWAY
```

This is all I could come up with.

Comment: SQL Server and SQLite are *completely* different products. I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte_borders as (
select country1 as from_country, country2 as to_country from borders
union all
select country2 as from_country, country1 as to_country from borders),
cte_germany_neighboors (from_country, to_country, hops) as (
select from_country, to_country, 0
  from cte_borders 
 where from_country = 'Germany' 
union all
select b.from_country, b.to_country, c.hops+1
  from cte_borders b
  join cte_germany_neighboors c
    on c.to_country = b.from_country 
 where c.hops < 4
   and b.from_country <> 'Germany')
select distinct 
       from_country as country,
       min(hops) as hops
  from cte_germany_neighboors
 group by from_country
 order by 2;
```

```
country |hops|
--------+----+
Germany |   0|
Austria |   1|
France  |   1|
Spain   |   2|
Portugal|   3|
```